# Visual studio mac, xamarin, no simulators shown

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

Just installed vs.net 2019 with Xamarin, and I got the error 'xcode 11.3.1 is currently selected...' with a button to install 11.5. Clicked that button, took me to a page to download xcode 12 beta, then I reluctantly upgraded to Catalina so I could install that. So once done, I switched Visual Studio preferences to point to that new XCode version. But I only have the option of selecting the generic build simulator. I updated deployment targets to 8.0 but it didn't help. When I launch xcode 12 beta, 'devices and simulators' shows a large list of them available. What else should I do?

Comment: Hi , do you mean that you have updated Mac OS and Xcode to the beta version , what's the previous version of VS ?

Comment: VS is 2019, that's the only version I have installed. Mac OS is Catalina, Xcode is 11.5 now (was 12 beta when I posted, but I subsequently removed that and installed 11.5 release version). Still have the issue.

Comment: Hi , remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Answer (score 0):

After dropping xcode to 11.5 and updating the minimum version in plist.info, the issue is resolved.